# Database exception - General error: 1021 Disk full

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody help me understand why this query says the disc is full?

**Database exception**

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full
>
> (/tmp/#sql_1445_3.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space...
>
> (errno: 28 "No space left on device")

[image: database exception]

**Query**
[image: the query]

Comment: The error itself is clear enough

Comment: Maybe the disk is full? Check your server's free space? `df -h`

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: If it says your disk is full, maybe your disk is full.

Comment: ya i know the disk full ...and then i free the database space n then run the query again it show the samething

Comment: the query is badly optimized and needs to have a MyiSAM disk based temporary table so MySQL can handle the results... You should optimize the table with INDEXES.. Please post a EXPLAIN [query] result here

Comment: @jazz if your problem is resolved accept the best answer (checking the green tick) instead answering one more time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a server problem. Only the host can solve it.

It means that /tmp is full. It's a very common error when you do too many backups.

Comment: so its means it doesnt have problem with the query  at all right? the server is the problem?

Comment: the real problem is that the query is badly optimized

Answer (score 5):

The error is provided by your SQL server, not your query.
You have to make space in server side, it doesn't have free space and can't execute any queries.

Comment: ouhh ok i get it ,so its mean the database is full, not the query that cause it. right?

Comment: No, it says that space disk is full, not the databse, you can't have a little databse on a server which doesn't have any free space. And yes it's a server error not the query

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was a long running process / queries
Check if there are long running process using

```
show full processlist
```

From list of process, check if any process is running for more time abnormally, read the ID from that response and kill it using below command

```
KILL 292372
```

This way we are able to recover all the free space, the below image shows what happened to free space on our RDS instance
[image: Free storage became 0 and then after killing process we have recovered]