# Mysql Disk space full, waiting for someone to free some space

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Sometimes my site is getting the error like the subject. Is there anything wrong with mysql query or the problem is from my server host?

Can anyone check my query here? is it badly query or no?

This code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT id,name,description,sort,status,listing_reg_type,listing_per_page,listing_fee,listing_reinvest_fee FROM groups {$gid}
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Become this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT id,name,description,sort,status,listing_reg_type,listing_per_page,listing_fee,listing_reinvest_fee FROM groups :gid
    ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':gid', $gid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Correct me if i'm wrong?

I need to contact my server each time this error come up. Anyone have solution for this?
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Anything wrong with the query? Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values. _But it would not cause this error_

Comment: _SMall Point_ Preparing a query with concatenated values is 1. unnecessary 2. No protection from SQL Injection

Comment: Please look next post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018980/database-exception-general-error-1021-disk-full/47019043

Comment: Please see my updated first post, is that what you mean? to change all $string in mysql SELECT become a bind_param?

Comment: How much spare disk space do you have?  How much in the tmp partition of disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to use prepared statements using PDO

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

Add this